# angular material table pagination, sorting and filtering

Tags: angular, angular-material

i'm trying to use angular material tab for pagination, filtering and sorting, but i got this exception :

> ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected.
> You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

What could be the problem?

#### user.component.ts

```js
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource: UserDataSource;
  displayedColumns = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'company'];
  myData: User[];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild('filter') filter: ElementRef;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUser()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.myData = res;
      })
    this.dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.myData, this.paginator, this.sort);
    Observable.fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .debounceTime(150)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe(() => {
        if (!this.dataSource) { return; }
        this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
      });
  }
}
```

#### UserDataSource

```js
export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  _filterChange = new BehaviorSubject('');
  get filter(): string { return this._filterChange.value; }
  set filter(filter: string) { this._filterChange.next(filter); }

  filteredData: User[] = [];
  renderedData: User[] = [];
  constructor(private data: User[], private paginator: MatPaginator, private sort: MatSort) {
    super();
    this._filterChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);

  }
  connect(): Observable<User[]> {
    const displayDataChanges = [
      this.data,
      this.sort.sortChange,
      this._filterChange,
      this.paginator.page,
    ];
    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
      // Filter data
      this.filteredData = this.data.slice().filter((item: User) => {
        let searchStr = (item.name).toLowerCase();
        return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) != -1;
      });

      const sortedData = this.sortData(this.filteredData.slice());

      const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
      this.renderedData = sortedData.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
      return this.renderedData;
    });

  }
  disconnect() { }

  sortData(data: User[]): User[] {
    if (!this.sort.active || this.sort.direction == '') { return data; }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      let propertyA: number | string = '';
      let propertyB: number | string = '';

      switch (this.sort.active) {
        case 'name': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.name, b.name]; break;
        case 'email': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.email, b.email]; break;
        case 'phone': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.phone, b.phone]; break;
        case 'company': [propertyA, propertyB] = [a.company.name, b.company.name]; break;
      }

      let valueA = isNaN(+propertyA) ? propertyA : +propertyA;
      let valueB = isNaN(+propertyB) ? propertyB : +propertyB;

      return (valueA < valueB ? -1 : 1) * (this.sort.direction == 'asc' ? 1 : -1);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML for the UserComponent?

Comment: edit your question and add html to that.

Answer (score 0):

My html code is:

```
<div>
    <div class="example-header" >
        <mat-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">
          <input matInput #filter placeholder="Filter users">
        </mat-input-container>
      </div>
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.name}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> E-Mail </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.email}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Phone </mat-header-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Company </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.company.name}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
    <div class="example-no-results"
    [style.display]="dataSource?.renderedData.length == 0 ? '' : 'none'">
 No users found matching filter.
</div>

<mat-paginator #paginator 
             [length]="dataSource?.filteredData.length"
             [pageIndex]="0"
             [pageSize]="25"
             [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
  </div>
```